# The requested PHP extension ext-mysql * is missing from your system. in php 7.1.7

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, composer-php

I am trying to deploy php app on heroku.
I have added tables to clearDB but stuck on this part:
after adding

```
"ext-mysql":"*"
```

this line  in composer. json it thows me error saying 
ERROR: Your 'composer.json' lists dependencies inside 'require', but no 'composer.lock' was found. Please run 'composer update' to re-generate 'composer.lock' if necessary, and commit it into your repository.

and after running

```
php composer.phar update
```

I get this error

```
The requested PHP extension ext-mysql * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mysql extension.
```

Comment: MySQL extension was removed in PHP 7 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Heroku is deploying php 7 directly , how can I specify not to use 7 but php 5

Comment: forget about old a danger mysql and PHP5, use PHP7 and mysqli/pdo.

Comment: If your app actually requires the old `mylsql_` API then you must use PHP5.6 or lower versions as the `mysql_` API was removed in PHP 7.0 never to be seen again

Comment: Please read the docs at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions, it outlines every step of what you have to do. The blue box describes exactly your problem (what to do if you do not have the extension locally and `composer update` fails).

Answer (score 6):

You can add  `--ignore-platform-reqs`

Full code:

```
php composer.phar update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will help

http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php

> PHP 5 users can choose between the deprecated mysql extension, mysqli, or PDO_MySQL. PHP 7 removes the mysql extension, leaving only the latter two options.

Comment: I have sql dump and have to use it

Comment: @Thesoham24 Try to archive that using mysqli or PDO. If it's your new project, edit your code. As PHP 7 has removed mysql so you can't use it or downgrade your PHP version to PHP 5. For quick editing you can refer to github there is a code for converting `mysql` to `mysqli` using GLOBAL object. IMO use PDO. That's the best option.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-fpm php7.2-cli php7.2-mysql php7.2-gd php7.2-imagick php7.2-recode php7.2-tidy php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-common php7.2-curl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml php7.2-bcmath php7.2-bz2 php7.2-intl php7.2-json php7.2-readline php7.2-zip
```

solve the question But I don't know why.